# Expected ',' separator error on formula in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I have a formula to calculate wind chill in my app, which requires air temperature and wind speed inputs. I used the following calculation from the website MentalFloss:

Wind Chill = 35.74 + 0.6215T – 35.75(V^0.16) + 0.4275T(V^0.16) where T is air temperature in degrees fahrenheit and V is wind speed in mph.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

infix operator ** {}

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{
    return pow(num, power)
}


class FirstViewController: UIViewController {    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtAirTemp: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var txtWindSpeed: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblWindChill1: UILabel!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }    

    @IBAction func btnShowWindChill(sender: UIButton) {

        var airTemp = Double((txtAirTemp.text as NSString).doubleValue)
        var windSpeed = Double((txtWindSpeed.text as NSString).doubleValue)

        lblWindChill1.text = "\((35.74 + 0.6215(airTemp) - 35.75(windSpeed**0.16) +       ((0.4275(airTemp))windSpeed**0.16)))"
    }

    @IBAction func btnIncreaseValue(sender: UIButton) {
    }


    @IBAction func btnDecreaseValue(sender: UIButton) {
    }

}
```

I'm getting the error "Expected ',' separator" in the lblWindChill1.text = formula lines in my btnShowWindChill event. Also there is a yellow arrow under the 'w' in windSpeed**0.16)))" toward the end of the formula, wanting to refactor, which doesn't help me. I added preceding zeros to my decimal numbers to no avail.

Is this a casting problem, or a problem with how I handled the exponent? Can someone please give me some ideas to fix this? BTW I haven't done anything with the btnIncreaseValue and btnDecreaseValue events yet.

If you can't tell, I'm somewhat of a beginner at this.

Thank you for whatever you can suggest!

Comment: To multiply, you need to have a `*`. Also, `**` doesn't exist as an operator.

Comment: The ** is the way I found to represent exponents. The ** was established as the exponent at the top of my code: infix operator ** {}

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{ return pow(num, power) }

Comment: @user2980343: Did you read the previous comment? For example, `0.6215(airTemp)` should be `0.6215 * airTemp`. Suggestion (if you are a beginner): start with a *simple* expression and then add more terms until you understand where the problem exactly is.

Comment: Let's try this again: The ** is the way I found to represent exponents. I think the ** was established as the exponent at the top of my code: 

infix operator ** {}

func ** (num: Double, power: Double) -> Double{ return pow(num, power) }

However, thank you so much, Jack Wu! Your pointer that I have to use * to multiply was all it took! The formula in my app is now: 

lblWindChill1.text = "\((35.74 + 0.6215*(airTemp) - 35.75*(windSpeed**0.16) + ((0.4275*(airTemp))*(windSpeed**0.16))))"

And the app runs and give me the correct Wind Chill! How do I give you a vote up?

Comment: I fixed my problem right away based on Jack's suggestion but I had trouble with the stack overflow comment/edit process ;) Thanks again!

Comment: I try the following and I get to complex. If I try to break it up I get speed is not a Bool.  var windchill = ((35.74 + 0.6215*(self.temperature) - 35.75*(speed^0.16) + ((0.4275*(self.temperature))*(speed^0.16))))